# ncks: Argument list too long

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, nco

I am trying to extract point information from a .nc file using two ids given in a data.txt
head of data.txt

```
AID CID
 730 285
 535 290
 736 291
```

can you help if there is any problem with this code? I am using Ubuntu in widows and anaconda Linux and getting an error "Argument list too long"

```
ids=`head -6 data.txt | awk '{if(NR>1) print $1}'`
echo $ids
ids=`cat data.txt | awk '{if(NR>1) print $1}'`
for id in $ids
do 
  aid=`cat data.txt | awk '{if($1=='${id}') print $1}'`
  rch=`cat data.txt | awk '{if($1=='${id}') print $2}'`
  index=`ncks -v rid ./file.nc | grep "$rch" | sed -e 's/rid\[//g' |awk 'BEGIN{FS="]"}{print $1}'`
  echo id=$id aid=$aid rch=$rch index={$index}
  ncks -O -v Qout -d rid,$index ./file.nc > temp.nc
 /bin/mv temp.nc data_aid${aid}_cid${rch}.nc
done
```

finally, i am expecting to get;

```
data_730_285.nc
data_535_290.nc
data_736_291.nc
.......
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error is probably from the second `ids` assignment. You can work around it by piping the data instead of storing it in a variable:

```
tail -n +2 data.txt | while read aid rch
do
  # ...  
done
```

---

Notes:

- your original `aid=...` line is equivalent to `aid=$id`
- I don't know what `ncks` does, but the subsequent `grep "$rch"` seems liable to false positives (numbers can be contained in other numbers (eg. 123 is also in 12345))
- `/bin/mv temp.nc data_aid${aid}_cid${rch}.nc` should be something like `/bin/mv temp.nc data_${aid}_${rch}.nc`

Comment: Hi Jhnc, thanks for checking, ncks extracts a variable "Qout" from a file.nc, and takes the "rid" of Qout.